# call_user_func_array + array_intersect with an array of array names, possible?

Tags: php, arrays

Sorry for the confusing title...

I need to perform an `array_intersect()` against a variable number of arrays. To do this it seems I need to use the `call_user_func_array()` function, however, this doesn't seem to be working and gives me the error:

```
Warning: array_intersect() [function.array-intersect]: Argument #1 is not an array in...
```

But, if I "print_r" the array to make sure then I see that it is an array:

```
Array ( [0] => arr_0 [1] => arr_1 )
```

My code (trimmed to just show the broken part):

```
$i = 0;
$arr_results = array();
foreach($arr_words as $word) {
    $arrayname = "arr_".$i;
    $$arrayname = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($search)) {
        array_push($$arrayname, $row['id']);
    }
    array_push($arr_results, "$arrayname");
    $i++
}
$matches = call_user_func_array('array_intersect',$arr_results);
```

In the full code I'm populating the arrays in the foreach loop with data obtained from sql queries.

Comment: `"$arrayname"` is a string, not an array. `call_user_func_array` will pass each element in  `$arr_results` as argument to `array_intersect`. `array_intersect` expects arrays as arguments, but each item in `$arr_results` is a string, not an array.

Comment: I take $arrayname and turn it into an array, I've just updated the code snippet to show this a bit better.

Comment: If that was true, `print_r` would show a nested array as output, but it shows an array of strings. Why do think `"$arrayname"` becomes an array? Where? *edit:* `array_push($arr_results, "$arrayname");` adds a string to the array. PHP is not evaluating the string. It does not now that the value in `$arrayname` refers to a variable name. Why don't you create an array of arrays from the beginning? That's much easier to handle than variable variables.

Comment: I didn't think that was right because "$arr_results" is an array of array names not a 3 dimensional array.

I turn "$arrayname" into an array with "$$arrayname = array();", this is then populated with data during the while loop.

Comment: But `array_intersect` expects arrays not array names. The names are strings.

Comment: So how do I pass multiple array names to array_intersect when the number of arrays is variable?

Comment: You don't pass *names*, you pass arrays. You have to create an array of arrays, not an array of array names... I will post something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my comments:

`"$arrayname"` is a string, not an array. `call_user_func_array` will pass each element in `$arr_results` as argument to `array_intersect`. `array_intersect` expects arrays as arguments, but each item in `$arr_results` is a string, not an array.

All you have to do is create an array of arrays instead of array names:

```
$arr_results = array();
foreach($arr_words as $word) {
    $ids = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($search)) {
        $ids[] = $row['id'];
    }
    $arr_results[] = $ids;
}
$matches = call_user_func_array('array_intersect',$arr_results);
```

> I turn `$arrayname` into an array with `$$arrayname = array();`

Right, you create a variable, lets say `arr_0` which will point to array. But there is still a difference between the variable name  `arr_0`  and the **string** containing the variable name `"arr_0"`. You create an array of strings, and that just won't work. PHP does not know that the string contains a name of a variable. For example, consider this:

```
$arr = "arr_0";
echo $arr[0];
```

Based on your logic, it should output the first element of the array, but it does not, because `$arr` is a string, not an array, although it contains the name of a variable.

You'd have to use `eval`, but you really should not. You could also use variable variables again:

```
array_push($arr_results, $$arrayname);
```

that would work as well, but as I said, variable variables are confusing and in 99% of the cases, you are better of with an array.

Comment: I no longer get the error but... this is now creating a new sub array for each row returned by the SQL query, so the array_intersect doesn't work as each array only has one entry. (Thanks for helping though, it is appreciated).

Comment: This is still returning an array where each row from the SQL query is a sub array...
The output of a print_r($ids) gives me:
`Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 40
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 42
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 61
        )`

Comment: Simple fix: `array($row['id'])` should be `$row['id']`. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Don't worry, fixed it, changed `$ids[] = array($row['id']);` to `array_push($ids, $row['storyid']);`.

Comment: Thanks for your help, you're a life saver and stopped me from banging my head against the wall.